# TextView not adding Dynamically

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

```
public class showStatus extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showstatus);


    addComments();
    }
```

if I call **addComments()** from here it is woring...

```
class sendCommentToWebsite extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String returnedComments;

    String comment, userName, MarkerID;

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... params) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String returnedComments) {

        super.onPostExecute(returnedComments);

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(returnedComments);
            for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObject.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonInnerObject = jsonObject
                        .getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));
                String comment = jsonInnerObject.getString("comment_text");
                String Comment_owner = jsonInnerObject
                        .getString("comment_owner");

                addComments(comment,Comment_owner);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//End of sendCommentToWebsite
```

*Now I want to add all the comments which is returned from website

*But from here addComments() is not working

*Another problem is I want all the dynamic TextView to have unique ID

*If this is not good way to save comments,Is there any other best way to save comments?

Because I want user to edit the comment if he tapping on comment for long time..

*Thank you

```
public void addComments(String comment, String comment_owner) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    RelativeLayout statusLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.showCommentLayout);

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv.setText(comment);
    this.statusLayout.addView(tv);

}//End of addComments
}//End of showStatus
```

Comment: You are better off using a listview

Comment: the code you posted does not either compile.

Comment: where does this - this.statusLayout. point to? are you referencing a different status layout than the one defined in the method's scope?

Comment: @David I have already tried this- statusLayout.addView(tv); but it's not working as well..

Answer (score 0):

For saving comments why don't you use Sqlite or SharedPreferences.

Comment: No I want to retrieve it from my server.